# All electricity in a room routed through a single light switch

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, light

I'm trying to install smart light switches in my home. I was doing the installation in my kitchen. The ceiling light in the kitchen only has one light switch, but when I opened it, to my surprise, I found wires for a 3-way. As a test, I just capped the third wire to see what would happen, and all the electricity went out in the kitchen (except the ceiling light). I have had a problem with the breaker tripping in the kitchen since I moved in, and I'm wondering if this can have something to do with it. It seems really odd to me to wire the electricity of the entire room through the light switch. Is this normal? (The house was built in the 80s)

The light switch I was planning to install doesn't have a 3-way. Is it safe to connect one of the hot wires with this 3-way through a hat?

Edit:
I added a piece of electrical tap to the extra wire that wires into the rest of the room so I can tell them apart.
[image]

The kitchen is on a single-width breaker.

How it was connected before I took the switch out.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not normal.  Add pictures of the switch and explain better about "all electricity" in the room, just lights or all the outlets also.

Comment: Breaker off, pull out switch, leaving wires connected, take clear pictures, [edit] them into your question. No, that does not seem right, but there's not *nearly* enough information to determine if you could do what you ask. You need to beware of possible Multi Wire Branch Circuits (MWBCs) in a kitchen (IME, if a house only has one, it will be a 20A serving the kitchen outlets.) Is the breaker affecting the kitchen single-width or double-width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That does not look like a 3-way setup.

Fairly normal to have always-hot power coming in to a switch and then going on to elsewhere, which would be two wires connected to one point on the switch (not two different points on the switch.) So that will normally be *always hot in*, connected to the switch **and** *always-hot out*, and then *switched hot out* connected to a different terminal on the switch.

1 & 3 are the same place on the switch, electrically. So that's doing always-hot in and always-hot out. You can join those two wires with a pigtail (short 3rd wire) to your new switch always-hot connection.

In a kitchen built under NEC in 1980, you **should** have two separate outlet circuits, not one. Thus, all kitchen outlets *should* not be on this one circuit.

Comment: You *must* join those two wires with a pigtail. No device is to be used as a pass through. Pulling a device should not affect anything 'upstream'. 1 & 3 are the same place? That doesn't make any sense. 3 connects to 1 or 2 depending on the position of the switch. The common makes contact with either traveler, not always one and sometimes another. But I'm not sure *how* this is working *at all* so I could be confused. - I'm not sure that's even a three way switch. Bootleg ground/neutral off of the switch? @OP, Is the screw for #3 black or... green?

Comment: 3 is the backwire of the screw at 1. Electrically, they are the same place. 1&3 are always connected. That is how it _was_ wired.

Comment: Oh... yeah, would've helped to have a pic before the shenanigans, like you said.